# Wikipedia like Indexes that list titles in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to make a php function that turns all my headers into a list of links. My current approach is doing this with a preg_replace

```
    $txt = preg_replace("#\[h1\](.+?)\[/h1\]#is", "<h2 style='display:inline;'>\\1</h3>", $txt);
$txt = preg_replace("#\[h2\](.+?)\[/h2\]#is", "<h3 style='display:inline; '>\\1</h4>", $txt);
```

So I got those two, but I can't seem to get the rest to dissapear. (because if I add one that deletes everything after this, I lose everything.)
So is there a regex that ommits my  tags and turns the rest into ""?

This is the way that seemed the most logical to me, but if there are simpler ways then I'm open for suggestions.

It grabs the code from my freshly made html file in body.html

```
$body = file_get_contents('body.html');
$text = replace_bb_code($body);
```

Comment: what you mean by "but I can't seem to get the rest to dissapear" what is that rest?

Comment: like `text text text <h1>Title</h1> text text text <h2>title</h2> text text` should become just `<h1>title</h1> <h2>title</h2>` (with some li tags in there, but that should be easy once this works.)

Comment: but you replacing into <h2> to </h3> :/

Comment: Oh yea, thas just bacause they were a bit large and I wanted to try that. You can ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear, but can you try this one:

```
$txt = preg_replace("#\[h2\](.+?)\[/h2\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|\[h2\])|.+$)#is", "<h2 style='display:inline;'>\\1</h2>", $txt);
$txt = preg_replace("#\[h1\](.+?)\[/h1\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|<h2)|.+$)#is", "<h1 style='display:inline;'>\\1</h1>", $txt);
```

how about this time :D I hope third time will not lie :D

Comment: This works works perfectly for that example, but not other cases. (I've probably been vague, but thats because I haven't slept tonight sorry. :P) There is an arbitrary amount of [h1]'s and [h2]'s in semi random orders. (Basically a [h1] with x [h2]'s under it, followed by a new [h1]  just like the content lists on wiki: http://i.imgur.com/jPI0EHz.png )

Comment: Here is a text file I got: http://pastebin.com/muu3pjFT (with wanted result on the bottom)

Comment: Your edit does not throw out the text in between btw. 

My current try is this: 
`$txt = preg_replace("#(.+?)\[h1\](.+?)\[/h1\](.+?)#is", "\\1<h1 style='display:inline;'>\\2</h1>\\3", $txt);
 $txt = preg_replace("#\[/h1\](.+?)\[h2\]#is", "", $txt);
 $txt = preg_replace("#\[/h2\](.+?)\[h2\]#is", "", $txt);
 $txt = preg_replace("#\[/h2\](.+?)\[h1\]#is", "", $txt);
 $txt = preg_replace("#\[h2\](.+?)\[\h2\]#is", "<h2 style='display:inline;'>\\1</h1>", $txt);`

But the oder is not right yet, as it is deleting too much :P

Comment: how about now? Maybe you will need just to remove text until first H1

Comment: Hmm this is odd. `$txt = preg_replace("#\[h2\](.+?)\[/h2\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|\[h2\])|.+$)#is", "<li><h2 style='display:inline;'>\\1</h2></li>", $txt);
$txt = preg_replace("#\[h1\](.+?)\[/h1\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|<h2)|.+$)#is", "</ul>\\1<ul>", $txt);`

If I turn it into a lo then it does not work for the top row. (none of em appear if I remove the <h2> tags, while the bottom one works fine like this.) Am I doing something wrong again? :P

Comment: if you first change into <li><h2 , then you need change second regex too. Like this $txt = preg_replace("#\[h1\](.+?)\[/h1\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|<li><h2)|.+$)#is", "</ul>\\1<ul>", $txt);

Comment: Yea just realised that myself xD The 2nd regex had to be changed. Thx again

Comment: `$txt = preg_replace("#\[h2\](.+?)\[/h2\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|\[h2\])|.+$)#is", "<li><a href=\"#\\1>\\1</a></li>", $txt);
$txt = preg_replace("#\[h1\](.+?)\[/h1\](.+?(?=\[h1\]|<li)|.+$)#is", "</ul><a href=\"#\\1>\\1</a><ul>", $txt);`

Got them like this now, and its totally tripping :P Not sure why :S

Comment: Gives me links like `newsletter.php/#ligula%20commodo%3Eligula%20commodo%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href=` where I want `newsletter.php/#ligula%20commodo` :P Also some titles dissapear now =/

Comment: can you give me again text at which you looking?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kx2dNqg1 With wanted result at bottom and link with current result

Comment: like and works but you need add double quotes inside href and then add las </ul> and remove first </ul>. change both replace to this part href=\"#\\1> to this href=\"#\\1\">

Comment: Works great! I love you :P
Last question, is there an easy way to replace the spaces in the link by `%20`'s ? `urlencode()` doesn't work sadly.

Comment: str_replace not help?